# togglebutton's click event in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, listbox, observablecollection

here is a part of a usercontrol I'm working on, a list of filenames where I can check a togglebutton to select some of them :

```
<ListBox x:Name="FileListBox" Template="{DynamicResource BaseListBoxControlStyle}" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource BaseListBoxItemStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.FileDisplay, ElementName=F_Selector, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Button x:Name="ListDelete" Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ListDelete}" Style="{DynamicResource BaseButtonStyle}" Margin="4,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="X" Click="FileDelete_Click"/>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="ListCheck" Click="ListCheck_Click" Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ListCheck}"  Margin="0,0,4,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource PathToFileName}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Now when I click a togglebutton I'm raising this event :

```
    private void ListCheck_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleButton btn = (ToggleButton)sender;
        int index = FileListBox.Items.IndexOf(btn.DataContext);
        if (btn.IsChecked == true)
        {
            FileSelected.Add(FileDisplay[index]);
        }
        else
        {
            FileSelected.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }
```

So I am adding/removing filename from this observablecollection :

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _FileSelected = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> FileSelected
    {
        get { return _FileSelected; }
        set { _FileSelected = value; }
    }
```

In my final project, this listbox usercontrol is contained into another usercontrol used 6 times into a (final) one.

When I test the usercontrol, checking randomly togglebuttons, I can see with the debugger that some filenames are duplicated in the collection and when that happens, an exception E0434352 is thrown.

Also, FileSelected is now an observablecollection, but if I make it a dependencyproperty of type observablecollection to be able to bind it, then it is always null and throw the same exception everytime I click a toggle.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ? thank you

Comment: (this is sketchy, I'm on my way out of the office, but i hope it helps): index is an index into FileDisplay. Don't use it to remove items from FileSelected, which has far fewer items. If only Item 3 is selected, FileSelected has ONE item in it. Then the user unchecks Item 3, and you remove item 3 from FileSelected, which has one item. Of course it throws an exception. You need to find the index of that item in FileSelected, which has its own IndexOf method. Also, if you want your dependency property to have an initial value, assign it one in the constructor.

Comment: that was it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two collections: `FileDisplay` and `FileSelected`. `FileSelected` holds a subset, at times an empty subset, of the items in `FileDisplay`.

Your variable `index` there is an index into `FileDisplay`. Where you're running into trouble is you're using it as an index into `FileSelected` as well. That's a problem because in virtually all cases, the two collections don't contain the same items in the same order.

Consider a case where you have five items in `FileDisplay`, the user selects `FileDisplay[2]`, and you add that item to `FileSelected`. Then he unselects that item, and you remove `FileSelected[2]`. It'll throw an exception because `FileSelected` has only one item, at index `0`.

You can then simplify it by not messing with indexes. `ObservableCollection<T>.Remove(T)` should work fine.

```
private void ListCheck_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ToggleButton btn = (ToggleButton)sender;
    int index = FileListBox.Items.IndexOf(btn.DataContext);
    var item = FileDisplay[index];

    //  This will probably work instead of messing with the index:
    //  var item = btn.DataContext as WhateverTypeFileSelectedContains;

    //  No need to compare a bool to true. 
    if (btn.IsChecked)
    {
        FileSelected.Add(item);
    }
    else if (FileSelected.Contains(item))
    {
        FileSelected.Remove(item);
    }
}
```